# Store in extjs contains data from multiple database tables having problems syncing

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, extjs

So, I have a store with a proxy to a hibernate named query in a entity class in java. the named query gets data from two different tables into this store. It loads the data just fine but when I'm trying to sync it with the db when a user updates a column, I get problems and the server can't find properties from the other table that the named query is pulling from.

For more context I have a store hooked up to a grid panel in extjs and it displays data from a database but one of the columns is from a different table than the other 3. I'm very new to extjs and I don't know if there's a better way to go about this and setup the store differently or if I should change the database to have the project name stored in both tables.

Here is my store code.

```
 job: {
            model: 'myefiles.jobs.pdd.model.Job',
            autoLoad: true,
            autoSync: false, // allow cell editing
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                url: '/dav/.json/pdd/job?.nq=findJobProjectMap', 
            timeout: myefiles.NO_TIMEOUT,
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    rootProperty: 'data'
                },
                writer: {
                    type: 'json',
                    allowSingle: false,
                    writeAllFields: true
                },
                noCache: false,
                limitParam: undefined,
                pageParam: undefined,
                startParam: undefined,
                listeners: {
                    exception: function(proxy, response, options) {
                        Ext.Msg.alert('Error', response.status + ": " + response.statusText
                                + " (" + response.request.options.url + ").");
                    }
                }
            }
        },
```

Here is my named query

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Job.findJobProjectMap",
                query = "SELECT new map (j.jobNumber as jobNumber, j.description as description, p.projectNumber as projectNumber, p.projectName as projectName) "
                        + "FROM Job j "
                        + "LEFT JOIN j.project as p")
```

the project name variable is in a different table called project and it isn't in the job table that this named query is in.

These are the column definitions in my entity class for the job table.

```
        @Id
    @Column(name = "job_number", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 6)
    @DBDavColumn
    protected Integer jobNumber;

    @Column(name = "description", length = 255)
    @DBDavColumn
    protected String description;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "project_number", referencedColumnName = "project_number")
    @DBDavColumn
    @DBDavConverter(factory=EntityConverterFactory.class)
    protected Project project;
    
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "job")
    protected Set<Equipment> equipment;
    
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "job")
    protected Set<MROData> mroData;
```

This is the model for the store

```
Ext.define('myefiles.jobs.pdd.model.Job', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    idProperty: 'jobNumber',
    fields: [{name: 'jobNumber', type: 'int', unique: true},
             {name: 'description', type: 'string'}, 
             {name: 'project', type: 'int'},
        {name: 'projectName', type: 'string'}
        ]
});
```

This is the extjs code for when the store is syncing when a button is pressed.

```
saveJob: function(button){
        console.log('AddJob grid save button is clicked.');
        //var store = Ext.getCmp('AdminAddJobGrid').getStore();
        var store = this.getViewModel().get().job;
        
        store.sync({
            success: function(){
                Ext.toast({
                    html: 'Data saved successfully.', 
                    title: 'Status',
                    width: 200,
                    align: 't'
                });
                //Ext.getCmp('AdminAddJobGrid').getStore().load(); // bad practice
                store.load();
                console.log('It worked!');
            },
            failure: function(form, response){
                Ext.Msg.alert('Status', 'Failed to save.');
                console.log('It failed');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

The logs for the server are saying STATUS 422 Could not find property for projectName

[This is the payload tab of what's sent to the server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNO2r.png)

Edit: So in the payload there was an extra variable called project this is because the model had a variable called project that was meant to be the project number so I changed that to project number and it got rid of that project variable in the payload that was equal to 0 the reason it recognizes the projectNumber but not the projectName I believe is because projectNumber is actually in the job table it's a foreign key that links jobs to project but project name is only in the project table. I'm trying to avoid having duplicate data in the two tables with the projectName column.

I'm also new to posting questions on here I hope I provided enough context.

Comment: Can you make a successful POST / PUT request with this payload to your backend independently from Ext JS, for example with Postman?